# Let $K = \mathbb{Q}\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right)$. Show that $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right)$. Can someone explain me how to show that

> $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]$  ?

I know that the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$, i.e. it contains the elements of $K$ which are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In this case, for every element of the field you can easily find a polynomial with intger coefficients which has it as a root. Can you use that?

Comment: Ok. I know how to find a monic polynomial with integer coefficients annihilating $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. Is this sufficient or do I have to show something more ?

Comment: Well, what does it mean for an element to be integral over $Z$?

Comment: An element $a$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ if there is a monic polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f(a) = 0$. The definition is clear to me. So $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, and that means that the whole ring generated by that is contained in the ring of integer elements, but you also need to prove the other inclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is proved in Dummit and Foote's book abstract algebra, 3rd edition, page 698, the first example. Just notice $\mathbb{Q}\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ and $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]$.